# Magento: unable to create table from local extension

Tags: database, mysql, install-script

My config.xml,

File Path: app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>

    <!-- Configure our module's behavior in the global scope -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          <modulename>
            <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
                <frontName>modulename</frontName>
              </args>
          </modulename>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>

        <models>
            <Namespace_Modulename>Namespace_Modulename_Model</Namespace_Modulename>

            <Modulename>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </Modulename>
            <Modulename_mysql4>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <Modulename>
                        <table>modulename</table>
                    </Modulename>
                </entities>
            </Modulename_mysql4>

        </models>

        <resources>
            <Modulename_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Modulename_setup>
            <Modulename_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </Modulename_write>
            <Modulename_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Modulename_read>
        </resources>

        <events>

            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_modulename_checkout_cart_product_add_after_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>onAddToCart</method>
                    </namespace_modulename_checkout_cart_product_add_after_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

        </events>

    </global>

</config>
```

My Observer.php

File Path: app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function onAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $name = $product->getName();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        Mage::log(
            "{$name} ({$sku}) updated",
            null,
            'product-updates.log'
        );
    }
}
```

Modulename.php, read filepath below,

File Path: app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Mysql4/Modulename.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Modulename extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {  
        $this->_init('modulename/modulename', 'modulename_id');
    }
}
```

Collection.php, read filepath below,

File Path: app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Mysql4/Modulename/Collection.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Modulename_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        //parent::__construct();
        $this->_init('modulename/modulename');
    }
}
```

mysql4-install-0.1.0.php, read filepath below,

File Path: app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/sql/modulename_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('modulename')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('modulename')} (
  `modulename_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `content` text NOT NULL default '',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`modulename_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

So these are all my available files for the extension `Namespace_Modulename`.

It works perfectly alright with no errors, system.log does not show any error.

When I add to cart, the entry is successfully logged and event is triggered. So this proves that extension is working properly.

Magento configuration: Logs are enabled and cache is disabled.

**My Problem:**
As you can see my file `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` above, it has a query of create table, but it is not creating the table when I check the database, no table is created.

**EDIT:**
List of all my tables: (You can see modulename table does not exist)

```
adminnotification_inbox
admin_assert
admin_role
admin_rule
admin_user
api2_acl_attribute
api2_acl_role
api2_acl_rule
api2_acl_user
api_assert
api_role
api_rule
api_session
api_user
captcha_log
cataloginventory_stock
cataloginventory_stock_item
cataloginventory_stock_status
cataloginventory_stock_status_idx
cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp
catalogrule
catalogrule_affected_product
catalogrule_customer_group
catalogrule_group_website
catalogrule_product
catalogrule_product_price
catalogrule_website
catalogsearch_fulltext
catalogsearch_query
catalogsearch_result
catalog_category_anc_categs_index_idx
catalog_category_anc_categs_index_tmp
catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx
catalog_category_anc_products_index_tmp
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
catalog_category_flat_store_1
catalog_category_product
catalog_category_product_index
catalog_category_product_index_enbl_idx
catalog_category_product_index_enbl_tmp
catalog_category_product_index_idx
catalog_category_product_index_tmp
catalog_compare_item
catalog_eav_attribute
catalog_product_bundle_option
catalog_product_bundle_option_value
catalog_product_bundle_price_index
catalog_product_bundle_selection
catalog_product_bundle_selection_price
catalog_product_bundle_stock_index
catalog_product_enabled_index
catalog_product_entity
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_gallery
catalog_product_entity_group_price
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_tier_price
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_index_eav
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp
catalog_product_index_eav_idx
catalog_product_index_eav_tmp
catalog_product_index_group_price
catalog_product_index_price
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_tmp
catalog_product_index_tier_price
catalog_product_index_website
catalog_product_link
catalog_product_link_attribute
catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
catalog_product_link_attribute_int
catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar
catalog_product_link_type
catalog_product_option
catalog_product_option_price
catalog_product_option_title
catalog_product_option_type_price
catalog_product_option_type_title
catalog_product_option_type_value
catalog_product_relation
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_attribute_label
catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing
catalog_product_super_link
catalog_product_website
checkout_agreement
checkout_agreement_store
cms_block
cms_block_store
cms_page
cms_page_store
core_cache
core_cache_option
core_cache_tag
core_config_data
core_email_queue
core_email_queue_recipients
core_email_template
core_flag
core_layout_link
core_layout_update
core_resource
core_session
core_store
core_store_group
core_translate
core_url_rewrite
core_variable
core_variable_value
core_website
coupon_aggregated
coupon_aggregated_order
coupon_aggregated_updated
cron_schedule
customer_address_entity
customer_address_entity_datetime
customer_address_entity_decimal
customer_address_entity_int
customer_address_entity_text
customer_address_entity_varchar
customer_eav_attribute
customer_eav_attribute_website
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
customer_form_attribute
customer_group
dataflow_batch
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
dataflow_import_data
dataflow_profile
dataflow_profile_history
dataflow_session
design_change
directory_country
directory_country_format
directory_country_region
directory_country_region_name
directory_currency_rate
downloadable_link
downloadable_link_price
downloadable_link_purchased
downloadable_link_purchased_item
downloadable_link_title
downloadable_sample
downloadable_sample_title
eav_attribute
eav_attribute_group
eav_attribute_label
eav_attribute_option
eav_attribute_option_value
eav_attribute_set
eav_entity
eav_entity_attribute
eav_entity_datetime
eav_entity_decimal
eav_entity_int
eav_entity_store
eav_entity_text
eav_entity_type
eav_entity_varchar
eav_form_element
eav_form_fieldset
eav_form_fieldset_label
eav_form_type
eav_form_type_entity
gift_message
importexport_importdata
index_event
index_process
index_process_event
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
newsletter_problem
newsletter_queue
newsletter_queue_link
newsletter_queue_store_link
newsletter_subscriber
newsletter_template
oauth_consumer
oauth_nonce
oauth_token
paypal_cert
paypal_payment_transaction
paypal_settlement_report
paypal_settlement_report_row
persistent_session
poll
poll_answer
poll_store
poll_vote
product_alert_price
product_alert_stock
rating
rating_entity
rating_option
rating_option_vote
rating_option_vote_aggregated
rating_store
rating_title
report_compared_product_index
report_event
report_event_types
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
report_viewed_product_index
review
```

**Solutions tried:**

-Cache refreshed (its disabled anyways)

-Changing version in config.xml to 0.1.0 and refreshing cache

-Renaming the version of mysql php file to 0.0.1 and refreshing cache

-Entry for "Modulename_setup" in the table core_resource deleted and then refreshed my homepage, it got created again but the table was still not created.

-Deleted "Modulename_setup" in the table core_resource and then inserted log in the mysql php file `Mage::log('testing', null, 'install.log', true); and see if the file var/log/install.log` and refreshed the page, "Modulename_setup" reappeared, but no log file was created, the script didn't get executed.

Comment: check entry in table "core_resource " for "Modulename_setup".if this entry is already there delete that row

Comment: It's not there Minish. Thanks for suggestion. No success however.

Comment: It was there, sorry, I deleted that and refreshed the page, but table was still not created in the database.

Comment: that is because your version mismatch issue as describe by Marius

Comment: no, it was because of the uppercase..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your module has the version 0.0.1 (`<version>0.0.1</version>`) but your install script is called `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`.
When installing the extension, Magento looks for the file `install-0.0.1.php` or `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`.
You should either change the version in config.xml to `0.1.0` or rename the install script to `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`.
But this won't be enough. Since your extension is already installed it won't run any install script again.
You need to go to the table `core_resource` and remove the line with `code = "Modulename_setup"`.
Clear the cache and load any page again so the extension will be reinstalled.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for replying, renamed the file, still didn't work. Then I changed in config.xml , still didn't work. I kept both versions same, 0.0.1 for both, and also tried 0.1.0 for both, none of them worked. And there is no entry for code="Modulename_setup" in my core_resource table.

Comment: try to debug your install script. Repeat the process again and add in your install script a log statement `Mage::log('testing', null, 'install.log', true);` and see if the file `var/log/install.log` gets created. if it doesn't it means your install script is not executed for a reason.

Comment: hey I rechecked:
Modulename_setup
0.1.0
0.1.0
was there, I deleted it and refreshed the page, it got created again, but the table was not created.

Comment: Inserted the log, no log was created, the script does not executed maybe , But I don't know why when "Modulename_setup" is being created successfully in core_resource table

Comment: in `config.xml` under the `<resources>` tag, do you have `<Modulename_setup>` or `<modulename_setup>`. It's really important. It should be lowercase.

Comment: You can see my config.xml file above, I have mentioned all the files, yeah its upper case, should I lower it? i will lower it and let you know after few minutes.

Comment: Oh it worked! Uppercase was the problem.